# Invoke a specific browser by URL

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Let's say I have a specific URL link and my default browser is Safari. Is there anyway for that URL to be opened using Chrome instead of the default browser by passing some parameter in the URL or any other way? Note that I do NOT want to change the default browser to Chrome.

Comment: What makes you think the user even has Chrome on their machines? Lots of large corporations limit employees to Windows and Internet Explorer, and it isn't possible for them to install another browser.

Comment: Let's just say we know the user has Chrome but is too lazy to start Chrome manually and just wants Chrome to start when that URL is accessed.

Answer (score 5):

The general way to solve this problem is to ask, "How can I launch Chrome with a specific URL?" Trying this on my machine, the command line

```
chrome http://stackoverflow.com
```

does it. So, you just need to:

- Locate `chrome.exe` on the user's machine
- Launch Chrome with a command line parameter of the URL you want to load

UPDATE: Upon rereading your question, I see that the user is browsing in Safari and wants to click on a link *in Safari* and open Chrome. No, there isn't any way to do this just by changing the HTML. My above answer would apply to a desktop program that wants to launch Chrome with a specific URL.

Answer (score 1):

you can not pass an url to be launched with a specific browser.

For that you would need access to the machine and start the specific browser yourself with the url as a parameter.

If you are just building a website you can not control this, but you could embedded some javascript telling the user that this site will only work if they are using chrome...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to this one but Choosy probably does exactly what you're looking for (Mac-only I believe): http://www.choosyosx.com.

Answer (score 0):

Found this gem and it does essentially this task by creating a Site Specific Browser.

It is a little different but it accomplishes the same goal!

http://lifehacker.com/5611711/create-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-for-mac-with-a-shell-script